# \ref counter for equation off by one for labels in align environment

Tags: numbering, amsmath

I'm having an issue where the \ref command typesets a number 1 higher than it should be for equations in align; equations are numbered correctly but the references are off.A \ref call to the last equation in align just prints ??. The equation environment works correctly.

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage[xdvi]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}
\begin{article}

\begin{align}
  vt=d\\\nonumber
  \label{eq:1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{t}=v\\\nonumber
  \label{eq:2}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  t=\frac{d}{v}\\\nonumber
  \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}

Here is the first reference: \ref{eq:1}

And here is the second: \ref{eq:2}

And here is the third: \ref{eq:3}

\end{article}
\end{document}
```

produces

Here is the first reference: 2

And here is the second: ??

And here is the third: 3

Comment: The problem is in the combinaton `\\ \nonumber
  \label{eq:1}` Why are you doing this (changing line, physically suppressing numbering of that empty line and placing the `\label` in that line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never have a trailing `\\` in environments like `align` or `gather`. You shouldn't use `align` or `gather` for one line displays, either. Moreover `\\` does nothing inside `equation`.

The `\label` command refers to the display line where it falls; giving it after `\nonumber` just confuses LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align}
vt          &= d \label{eq:1} \\
\frac{d}{t} & =v \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{d}{v}  \label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

Here is the first reference: \ref{eq:1}

And here is the second: \ref{eq:2}

And here is the third: \ref{eq:3}

\end{article}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Final notes**
The `lipsum` package is just for providing text. Don't use the `xdvi` option for `graphicx`: it exists, but only for backwards compatibility. If you don't use a driver such as `dvipdfmx`, no option should be given. I also removed the packages not necessary for the example.